# Return value from stored procedure using scope_identity()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored proc with two insert statements.  I would like to return the ID from the first insert.  It looks broadly like this:

```
declare @retVal int
Begin transaction

insert into myTable(..) values (..)

set @retVal = scope_identity()

insert into myTable2(..) values(..)

Commit transaction

return @retVal
```

When I do this, the insert statements work fine but the same value is returned every time (in this case, ID 6 from `myTable`, for some strange reason.)

Would anyone have a guess on what's going on?

Comment: it would help to see the complete schema setup, including table creates and full tsql. There is nothing wrong with what you posted, but I suspect your actual code is more complex?

Comment: don't use return ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174998(v=sql.105).aspx )
I suggest you replace *RETURN* with *SELECT* and it should work

Comment: Or use an output parameter...

Comment: @Thomas why do you think `SELECT` is better? You want to require all the scaffolding of retrieving a resultset, potentially using a DataReader, etc. to retrieve a single, scalar value? `OUTPUT` is far more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Is the ID column on myTable an `IDENTITY` column or is the ID created/populated via a trigger?

Comment: @Love2Learn-- it's an IDENTITY column, declared `[int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` in the schema

Comment: Agreed output param is the right way to do it, but nothing syntactically wrong w/ return in his script. Definitely nothing that would return 6. Simply changing to `select` instead of return is unlikely to fix it. Need to see the full picture.

Comment: @Nathan the only thing I can envision is a trigger on myTable that inserts into a table with identity seed set to 6 and then truncates the table. Seems far-fetched at best. :-) Another possibility is the application code is not correctly pulling the return value. Could be grabbing row count, or who knows what else...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, could be the culprit.  Triggers, aka land mines :)

Comment: So, @larryq, is there a trigger on `myTable`? Could you share it? Could you also share the code where you are retrieving the return value and seeing 6 every time?

Comment: Shouldn't scope identity ignore whatever happens in the trigger? `@@Identity` would be affected by triggers, but I thought `Scope_Identity` was safe.

Comment: I'm stumped, the only thing I can figure is the stored procedure is being wrapped in a transaction that is being rolled back for testing purposes and therefore returns the same value each time. XD

Comment: @Aaron-- I'm checking the trigger thing, but this is a brand new set of tables and I've seen the schemas for both.  We don't generally use triggers here so I'd be surprised...

Comment: @Aaron et al.-- also working feverishly to convert to an output parameter on this, to see if it helps.

Comment: @Love2Learn yes you're right about scope_identity. But you're wrong about rollback. IDENTITY values are issued and not rolled back.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Wow, I'm kind of surprised that I didn't know that. That seems pretty basic. Thanks for filling in the gap. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use an `OUTPUT` parameter. `RETURN` is for returning status/error codes, not data. For example, `RETURN` only handles `INT`. Guess what happens when you change your table to use `BIGINT` because `INT` wasn't enough?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure
  @params VARCHAR(32),
  @Table1ID INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT dbo.Table1...
  SET @Table1ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  INSERT dbo.Table2...

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

Comment: Using an output parameter did the trick, thanks very much to everyone.  I'm happy to go that route from here on.

Comment: It returning both @Table1ID  value and RETURN value... how to supress only the Table1ID  ?

Comment: Sorry @bhat, I don't understand the issue. Maybe you should create a new question.